# .htaccess rewrite help, remove .php from URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not facing another problem with my mod_rewrite, first, time is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /news?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/([0-9]+)/?$ /contact?do=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /account?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /admin?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^login/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /login?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /register?action=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] <- This line doesn't work
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

All lines are working, beside the **RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]** 
and when I use this line, all other rules gets interrupted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `L` flag in your problematic rule.

For removing the .php extension this is better rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /news?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/([0-9]+)/?$ /contact?do=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /account?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /admin?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^login/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /login?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /register?action=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it wont show home page, some pages do work, and the pages where I want to remove .php doesn't work

Comment: www.domain.com doesn't work, www.domain.com/about does work, www.domain.com/api/file doesn't work, www.domain.com/api/file.php does work, the 2 first URLs are routed thru index, as you see in the .htaccess file :)

Comment: it should show home.phtml, the about link is also routing to about.phtml which works

Comment: 1. You wanted to hide `.php` not `.phtml`. 2. Where is the code that says show `home.phtml` for `www.domain.com`?

Comment: when you visit domain.com then the index routes into /templates/home.phtml, if I go to domain.com/about, then the rules makes it domain.com/index.php?page=about, it all routed thru PHP in index, .phtml is removed because of the routing, and the rule: **RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]** does so it doesn't need to say index.php?page=about, but just .domain.com/about, so there is no .phtml, and on the site, there is either no .php, but I have an API service on the site to, and which ain't included in the routing, so I need to put api/file.php and I want to remove the .php

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: A1. Yes, this is the only one. A2. Yes, this is the only code in it. A3. it is located in root webfolder

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
#Preventing loop 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+\.php.*$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Put this after `RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /register?action=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: when I do that, then the page is going in an never ending loop :/

Comment: See above, i fix the tip